# Setting character encoding with request parameter

Tags: java, servlets, character-encoding

Is it possible to pass a request param containing the encoding to a filter which checks if there is a value and sets it as character encoding? I have read that calling the method to setting the character encoding should be done before reading the request params. Is there maybe another way to do this?

Edit: Java / Java Server Pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is solved in [Detect the URI encoding automatically in Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2657515/detect-the-uri-encoding-automatically-in-tomcat).