# Detect the URI encoding automatically in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, character-encoding, servlet-filters, url-encoding

I have an instance of Apache Tomcat 6.x running, and I want it to interpret the character set of incoming URLs a little more intelligent than the default behavior. In particular, I want to achieve the following mapping:

```
So%DFe => Soße
So%C3%9Fe => Soße
So%DF%C3%9F => (error)
```

The bevavior I want could be described as "try to decode the byte stream as UTF-8, and if it doesn't work assume ISO-8859-1".

Simply using the `URIEncoding` configuration doesn't work in that case. So how can I configure Tomcat to encode the request the way I want?

I might have to write a Filter that takes the request (especially the query string) and re-encodes it into the parameters. Would that be the natural way?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The complicated way to achieve my goal was indeed to write my own `javax.servlet.Filter` and to embed it into the filter chain. This solution complies with the Apache Tomcat suggestion provided in [Tomcat Wiki - Character Encoding Issues](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding#Q3).

**Update (2010-07-31):** The first version of this filter interpreted the query string itself, which was a bad idea. It didn't handle `POST` requests correctly and had problems when combined with other servlet filters like for URL-rewriting. This version instead wraps the originally provided parameters and recodes them. To make it work correctly, the `URIEncoding` (for example in Tomcat) must be configured to be `ISO-8859-1`.

```java
package de.roland_illig.webapps.webapp1;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.CharBuffer;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.charset.CharsetDecoder;
import java.nio.charset.CodingErrorAction;
import java.nio.charset.IllegalCharsetNameException;
import java.nio.charset.UnsupportedCharsetException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Automatically determines the encoding of the request parameters. It assumes
 * that the parameters of the original request are encoded by a 1:1 mapping from
 * bytes to characters.
 * <p>
 * If the request parameters cannot be decoded by any of the given encodings,
 * the filter chain is not processed further, but a status code of 400 with a
 * helpful error message is returned instead.
 * <p>
 * The filter can be configured using the following parameters:
 * <ul>
 * <li>{@code encodings}: The comma-separated list of encodings (see
 * {@link Charset#forName(String)}) that are tried in order. The first one that
 * can decode the complete query string is taken.
 * <p>
 * Default value: {@code UTF-8}
 * <p>
 * Example: {@code UTF-8,EUC-KR,ISO-8859-15}.
 * <li>{@code inputEncodingParameterName}: When this parameter is defined and a
 * query parameter of that name is provided by the client, and that parameter's
 * value contains only non-escaped characters and the server knows an encoding
 * of that name, then it is used exclusively, overriding the {@code encodings}
 * parameter for this request.
 * <p>
 * Default value: {@code null}
 * <p>
 * Example: {@code ie} (as used by Google).
 * </ul>
 */
public class EncodingFilter implements Filter {

  private static final Pattern PAT_COMMA = Pattern.compile(",\\s*");

  private String inputEncodingParameterName = null;
  private final List<Charset> encodings = new ArrayList<Charset>();

  @Override
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
    String encodingsStr = "UTF-8";

    Enumeration<String> en = config.getInitParameterNames();
    while (en.hasMoreElements()) {
      final String name = en.nextElement();
      final String value = config.getInitParameter(name);
      if (name.equals("encodings")) {
        encodingsStr = value;
      } else if (name.equals("inputEncodingParameterName")) {
        inputEncodingParameterName = value;
      } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown parameter: " + name);
      }
    }

    for (String encoding : PAT_COMMA.split(encodingsStr)) {
      Charset charset = Charset.forName(encoding);
      encodings.add(charset);
    }
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  @Override
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest sreq, ServletResponse sres, FilterChain fc) throws IOException, ServletException {
    final HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) sreq;
    final HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) sres;

    final Map<String, String[]> params;
    try {
      params = Util.decodeParameters(req.getParameterMap(), encodings, inputEncodingParameterName);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      res.sendError(400, e.getMessage());
      return;
    }

    HttpServletRequest wrapper = new ParametersWrapper(req, params);
    fc.doFilter(wrapper, res);
  }

  @Override
  public void destroy() {
    // nothing to do
  }

  static abstract class Util {

    static CharsetDecoder strictDecoder(Charset cs) {
      CharsetDecoder dec = cs.newDecoder();
      dec.onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.REPORT);
      dec.onUnmappableCharacter(CodingErrorAction.REPORT);
      return dec;
    }

    static int[] toCodePoints(String str) {
      final int len = str.length();
      int[] codePoints = new int[len];
      int i = 0, j = 0;
      while (i < len) {
        int cp = Character.codePointAt(str, i);
        codePoints[j++] = cp;
        i += Character.charCount(cp);
      }
      return j == len ? codePoints : Arrays.copyOf(codePoints, len);
    }

    public static String recode(String encoded, CharsetDecoder decoder) throws IOException {
      byte[] bytes = new byte[encoded.length()];
      int bytescount = 0;

      for (int i = 0; i < encoded.length(); i++) {
        char c = encoded.charAt(i);
        if (!(c <= '\u00FF'))
          throw new IOException("Invalid character: #" + (int) c);
        bytes[bytescount++] = (byte) c;
      }

      CharBuffer cbuf = decoder.decode(ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes, 0, bytescount));
      String result = cbuf.toString();
      return result;
    }

    static String ensureDefinedUnicode(String s) throws IOException {
      for (int cp : toCodePoints(s)) {
        if (!Character.isDefined(cp))
          throw new IOException("Undefined unicode code point: " + cp);
      }
      return s;
    }

    static Map<String, String[]> decodeParameters(Map<String, String[]> originalParams, List<Charset> charsets, String ieName) throws IOException {
      Map<String, String[]> params = new LinkedHashMap<String, String[]>();

      Charset ie = null;
      {
        String[] values = originalParams.get(ieName);
        if (values != null) {
          for (String value : values) {
            if (!value.isEmpty() && value.indexOf('%') == -1) {
              try {
                if (ie != null)
                  throw new IOException("Duplicate value for input encoding parameter: " + ie + " and " + value + ".");
                ie = Charset.forName(value);
              } catch (IllegalCharsetNameException e) {
                throw new IOException("Illegal input encoding name: " + value);
              } catch (UnsupportedCharsetException e) {
                throw new IOException("Unsupported input encoding: " + value);
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }

      Charset[] css = (ie != null) ? new Charset[] { ie } : charsets.toArray(new Charset[charsets.size()]);
      for (Charset charset : css) {
        try {
          params.clear();
          CharsetDecoder decoder = strictDecoder(charset);
          for (Map.Entry<String, String[]> entry : originalParams.entrySet()) {
            final String encodedName = entry.getKey();
            final String name = ensureDefinedUnicode(Util.recode(encodedName, decoder));
            for (final String encodedValue : entry.getValue()) {
              final String value = ensureDefinedUnicode(Util.recode(encodedValue, decoder));
              String[] oldValues = params.get(name);
              String[] newValues = (oldValues == null) ? new String[1] : Arrays.copyOf(oldValues, oldValues.length + 1);
              newValues[newValues.length - 1] = value;
              params.put(name, newValues);
            }
          }
          return params;
        } catch (IOException e) {
          continue;
        }
      }

      List<String> kvs = new ArrayList<String>();
      for (Map.Entry<String, String[]> entry : originalParams.entrySet()) {
        final String key = entry.getKey();
        for (final String value : entry.getValue()) {
          kvs.add(key + "=" + value);
        }
      }
      throw new IOException("Could not decode the parameters: " + kvs.toString());
    }
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  static class ParametersWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {

    private final Map<String, String[]> params;

    public ParametersWrapper(HttpServletRequest request, Map<String, String[]> params) {
      super(request);
      this.params = params;
    }

    @Override
    public String getParameter(String name) {
      String[] values = params.get(name);
      return (values != null && values.length != 0) ? values[0] : null;
    }

    @Override
    public Map getParameterMap() {
      return Collections.unmodifiableMap(params);
    }

    @Override
    public Enumeration getParameterNames() {
      return Collections.enumeration(params.keySet());
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getParameterValues(String name) {
      return params.get(name);
    }
  }
}
```

While the code size is reasonably small, there are some implementation details that one can get wrong, so I would have expected that Tomcat already delivers a similar filter.

To activate this filter, I have added the following to my `web.xml`:

```xml
<filter>
  <filter-name>EncodingFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>de.roland_illig.webapps.webapp1.EncodingFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>encodings</param-name>
    <param-value>US-ASCII, UTF-8, EUC-KR, ISO-8859-15, ISO-8859-1</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>inputEncodingParameterName</param-name>
    <param-value>ie</param-value>
  </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>EncodingFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

We already did something similar to Roland's solution on SGES2.1.1 (I thing it uses catalina same as some old Tomcats), but it had some problems:

1. it duplicates what the application server does
2. it must take care also to internal JSP requests, included pages with parameters ...
3. it must parse query string
4. it must do it all again everytime is setRequest called, but later, because of 2.
5. it is too heavy workaround

Today, after I read many blogs and advices I deleted the whole class and did only one simple thing: parsed charset from the Content-Type header in the wrapper's constructor and set it to the wrapped instance.

It works, all our 988 tests succeeded.

```
private static final Pattern CHARSET_PATTERN 
    = Pattern.compile("(?i)\\bcharset=\\s*\"?([^\\s;\"]*)");
private static final String CHARSET_DEFAULT = "ISO-8859-2";

public CisHttpRequestWrapper(final HttpServletRequest request) {
  super(request);
  if (request.getCharacterEncoding() != null) {
    return;
  }
  final String charset = parseCharset(request);
  try {
    setCharacterEncoding(charset);
  } catch (final UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("Unknown charset: " + charset, e);
  }
}

private String parseCharset(final HttpServletRequest request) {
  final String contentType = request.getHeader("Content-Type");
  if (contentType == null || contentType.isEmpty()) {
    return CHARSET_DEFAULT;
  }
  final Matcher m = CHARSET_PATTERN.matcher(contentType);
  if (!m.find()) {
    return CHARSET_DEFAULT;
  }
  final String charsetName = m.group(1).trim().toUpperCase();
  return charsetName;
}
```

Comment: Remained only one problem: Encoding of the original HTTP request after user login is corrupted - it was bug in catalina; it does not occur on Glassfish4 and also can be prevented with sun-web.xml where can be set a default request charset.