# Servlet receiving data both in ISO-8859-1 and UTF-8. How to URL-decode?

Tags: servlets, utf-8, character-encoding, iso-8859-1

I've a web application (well, in fact is just a servlet) which receives data from 3 different sources:

- Source A is a HTML document written in UTF-8, and sends the data via `<form method="get">`.
- Source B is written in ISO-8859-1, and sends the data via `<form method="get">`, too.
- Source C is written in ISO-8859-1, and sends the data via `<a href="http://my-servlet-url?param=value&param2=value2&etc">`.

The servlet receives the request params and URL-decodes them using UTF-8. As you can expect, A works without problems, while B and C fail (you can't URL-decode in UTF-8 something that's encoded in ISO-8859-1...).

I can make slight modifications to B and C, but I am not allowed to change them from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8, which would solve all the problems.

In B, I've been able to solve the problem by adding `accept-charset="UTF-8"` to the `<form>`. So it sends the data in UTF-8 even with the page being ISO.

What can I do to fix C?

Alternatively, is there any way to determine the charset on the servlet, so I can call URL-decode with the right encoding in each case?

---

**Edit**: I've just found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2657515/detect-the-uri-encoding-automatically-in-tomcat), which seems to solve my problem. I still have to make some tests in order to determine if it impacts the perfomance, but I think I'll stick with that solution.

Comment: How about `<input type="hidden" name="charset" value="??? profit!" />`?

Comment: Hmmm.. I would prefer not to add more parameters to the request... but I guess that way it should work. I'll try it. Thanks! :)

Comment: In that approach, I think that Google main search page includes (or included) an "ie" parameter... Too lazy for test it now http://www.seomoz.org/ugc/the-ultimate-guide-to-the-google-search-parameters

Comment: Yes, it does. "ie" for input encoding, "oe" for output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering myself in order to mark the question as solved:

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2657515/detect-the-uri-encoding-automatically-in-tomcat), which covers exactly the same problem I was facing. The `javax.servlet.Filter` was the solution for me.

Answer (score 3):

The browser will by default send the data in the same encoding as the requested page was returned in. This is controllable by the HTTP [`Content-Type`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.17) header which you can also set using the HTML `<meta>` tag.

The `accept-charset` attribute of the HTML `<form>` element should be avoided since it's broken in MSIE. Almost all non-UTF-8 encodings are ignored and will be sent in platform default encoding (which is usually CP-1252 in case of Windows).

To fix A and B (POST) you basically need to set [`HttpServletRequest#setCharacterEncoding()`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#setCharacterEncoding%28java.lang.String%29) before gathering request parameters. Keep in mind that this is an one-time task. You cannot get a parameter and then change the encoding and then "re-get" the parameters.

To fix C (GET) you basically need to set the request URI encoding in the server configuration. Since it's unclear which server you're using, here's a Tomcat-targeted example: in the [HTTP connector](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/http.html) set the following attribute:

```
<Connector (...) URIEncoding="ISO-8859-1" />
```

However, this is already the default encoding in most servers. So you maybe don't need to do anything for C.

As an alternative, you can grab the raw and un-URL-encoded data from the request body (in case of POST) by [`HttpServletRequest#getInputStream()`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getInputStream%28%29) or from the query string (in case of GET) by [`HttpServletRequest#getQueryString()`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getQueryString%28%29) and then *guess* the encoding yourself based on the characters available in the parameters and then [URL-encode](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) accordingly using the guessed encoding. A hidden input element with a specific character which is different in both UTF-8 and ISO-8859-1 may help a lot in this.

Comment: Are you sure that `accept-encoding` only works in MSIE? My ISO-8859-1 page is now sending the data correctly in UTF-8 (tried it in Chrome and Firefox).

The problem I face is that I don't know which encoding is being used in each case, ISO-8859-1 or UTF-8. So I can't use `setCharacterEncoding()`. I hope that zildjohn01's suggestion will help to determine it.