# How to set the "Content-Type ... charset" in the request header using a HTML link

Tags: html, character-encoding, special-characters, urlencode

I have a simple HTML-page with a UTF-8 encoded link.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <a charset='UTF-8' href='http://server/search?q=%C3%BC'>search for "ü"</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

However, I don't get the browser to include `Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8` into the request header. Therefore I have to configure the web server to assume all requests are UTF-8 encoded (URIEncoding="UTF-8" in the [Tomcat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Tomcat) *server.xml* file). But of course the admin won't let me do that in the production environment ([WebSphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_WebSphere)).

I know it's quite easy to achieve using Ajax, but how can I control the request header when using standard HTML links? The `charset` attribute doesn't seem to work for me (tested in [Internet Explorer 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_8) and Firefox 3.5)

The second part of the required solution would be to set the URL encoding when changing an IFrame's `document.location` using JavaScript.

Comment: The `charset` attribute is not very useful and is now deprecated.  See this related question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17199047/does-adding-charset-utf-8-to-an-html-link-element-have-any-effect

Comment: The question you linked to isn't really related to this one. However it's quite obvious that <link charset='' is deprecated. +1

Comment: Yes, I am *not* saying the two questions are duplicates.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is not possible from HTML on.

The closest what you can get is the `accept-charset` attribute of the `<form>`. Only Internet Explorer adheres that, but even then it is doing it wrong (e.g., CP-1252 is *actually* been used when it says that it has sent ISO-8859-1). Other browsers are fully ignoring it and they are using the charset as specified in the `Content-Type` header of the response.

Setting the character encoding right is basically fully the responsibility of the server side. The client side should just send it back in the same charset as the server has sent the response in.

To the point, you should really configure the character encoding stuff entirely from the server side on. To overcome the inability to edit the `URIEncoding` attribute, someone here on Stack Overflow wrote a (complex) filter: *[Detect the URI encoding automatically in Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2657515/detect-the-uri-encoding-automatically-in-tomcat)*. You may find it useful as well (note: I haven't tested it).

---

Noted should be that the meta tag as given in your question is **ignored** when the content is been transferred over HTTP. Instead, the HTTP response `Content-Type` header will be used to determine the content type and character encoding. You can determine the HTTP header with for example [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com), in the *Net* panel.

[image]

Comment: Ok, thanks. I seem to get it now. But how do I set the charset at server-side? My initial page is a static html file with `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">` but the webserver ships it without charset-information in the HTTP header. Do you know of any resources about how the encoding info in the HTTP and HTML header are supposed to work together? Why do we need both of them?

Comment: The meta tag is ignored when the page is served over HTTP (see answer update). When using JSP, you should put `<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>` in top. When using Servlet, you should do `response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");`. Both will implicitly set the right charset in the content type header. You may find this article useful: [Unicode - How to get characters right?](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html). For JSP/Servlet solutions, start at [this chapter](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html#JSPServletRequest).

Comment: Awesome. Everyday I learn something like this is certainly a great day.

Comment: @BalusC : I found a server which allow it’s users to upload arbitrary contents but always sets the same Content type.`X-Content-Type-Options`isn’t set, but modern browsers tend to no longer do mime type sniffing. **So is there a way to override the server supplied mime type with ʜᴛᴍʟ ?** *(ignoring what html attributes are stripped)*