# Character encoding of HTML form

Tags: php, html, character-encoding

i have a page in iso-8859-1

```
<meta http-equiv=content-type content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
```

and two forms in the page, one form submits to the same page and another submits to a different page

```
<form method='post' action='post.php'>
</form>
```

i insert comments added in different language to post.php page and insert it.
In firebug when i see the charset it says

```
application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
```

Which creates the problem as posted data is saved properly because of different encoding

is there a way to change the encoding of the form to iso-8859-1, which will work for me as , i have tried the same insertion of comments in the same page and it work with the iso-8859-1 encoding

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6228960/how-to-set-the-content-type-charset-in-the-request-header-using-a-html-lin

Is this helpful?

Comment: If the page encoding is declared as iso-8859-1 and the form does not have an `accept-charset` attribute, then form submission will use windows-1252 (which is what iso-8859-1 is really mapped to on the Web). So if the form encoding is actually utf-8, then the premises are not true. We would really need to see the HTTP headers of the page to be sure of its declared encoding.

Comment: Please try to clarify the question by constructing a demo page that has just one form (unless two forms are needed to reproduce the problem) and post its URL and/or the page content plus the HTTP response headers.

Comment: Two forms are required to replicate the problem, the form which post to external page uses charset UTF-8, but i want that to be iso-8859-1, if i post to the same page and check the encoded value for the fonts its correct in same page.

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use utf-8 for the page what your form is on it, and post.php

all the page should have a same charset

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```