# MTOM - Root content type was always text/xml

Tags: java, soap, websphere, websphere-liberty, mtom

I am using MTOM to stream the attached file from client to the server.

The MTOM gets applied and the file is streamed as binary. But the root Content-Type was always **"text/xml"** which should be "application/xml+xop".

The problems occurs only in **websphere**. The content type was set as **"text/xml"** in websphere.

In **websphere liberity profile**, the content type was set as **"application/xml+xop"**

```
------=_Part_7283_-2062365125.1458743649653
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-Id: <511212039242.1458743649653.IBM.WEBSERVICES@lsrv4665.linux.rabobank.nl>

    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <soapenv:Header>
        </soapenv:Header>
        <soapenv:Body>
          <Content><xop:Include xmlns:xop="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include" href="cid:58cf03d2-322f-4819-80fb-3b001f497d12%40www.test.com"/>
          </Content>
        </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>

    Content-Type: application/pdf; name=attachment.pdf

Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Able to resolve this issue by using saaj-impl jar.

**pom.xml**

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj</groupId>
    <artifactId>saaj-impl</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.16</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
 </dependency>
```

**dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<bean id="messageFactory" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory">
  <property name="messageFactory">
    <bean class="com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.SOAPMessageFactory1_1Impl" />
  </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Thanks AJJ. Your solution really helped me.

Answer (score 1):

I have gathered couple of answers. Hope first answer will be fit for you. For precautions, i have also added some other answer with links. Hope it will save you.

### Ans-1:

**server side (JAX-WS in Weblogic)**

use `@MTOM` annotation or `mtom.xml` policy

**client side (JAX-WS in Weblogic)**

```
Pass MTOMFeature() as argument:
MtomService port = service.getMailServicePort(new MTOMFeature());
```

MTOM attachment via SOAPUI, 3 steps:

1. `Set Enable MTOM = true` in the request properties
2. Upload the attachment (e.g.. A3.pdf), notice the contentID
3. Set the MTOM contentID in the xml request

Here is a full example with images with weblogic. Hope it will fit with your issue.(link for [Sending attachment: MTOM / XOP vs SWA and inline attachment](http://soa-java.blogspot.com/2012/09/mtom-email-attachment.html))

Another Resource Link:

1. [Steps to Use MTOM/XOP to Send Binary Data](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/web.1111/e13734/mtom.htm#WSADV133)
2. [Error consuming webservice, content type “application/xop+xml” does
   not match expected type “text/xml”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10496186/error-consuming-webservice-content-type-application-xopxml-does-not-match-ex)

---

### Ans-2:

Pulling in `saaj-impl 1.3.23` and preferring application classes for `javax.xml.soap.*` resolved this issue.

Resource Link: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SWS-855

---

### Ans-3:

From mkyong's [tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-attachment-with-mtom/), it can be solved enabling mtom on client and server.

**Enabling MTOM on server:**

Enable server to send attachment via MTOM is very easy, just annotate the web service implementation class with `javax.xml.ws.soap.MTOM`.

**Enabling MTOM on client:**

Enable client to send attachment via MTOM to server is required some extra efforts, see following example :

```
//codes enable MTOM in client
BindingProvider bp = (BindingProvider) imageServer;
SOAPBinding binding = (SOAPBinding) bp.getBinding();
binding.setMTOMEnabled(true);
```

---

### Ans-4

Credit goes to @[BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc). He has given an awesome answer with his great tutorial.

The meta tag is ignored when the page is served over HTTP.

**When using JSP,**

you should put `<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>` in top.

**When using Servlet,**

you should do `response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");`.

Both will implicitly set the right charset in the content type header. You may find this article useful: [Unicode - How to get characters right?](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html). For JSP/Servlet solutions, start at [this chapter](http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html#JSPServletRequest).

Resource Link:

1. [How to set the "Content-Type ... charset" in the request header using a HTML link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6228960/how-to-set-the-content-type-charset-in-the-request-header-using-a-html-lin)

---

### For research, you can go through followings

For a Java servlet, you should have the line

`response.setContentType("text/html");`

at the top of your `doGet` or `doPost` method, where response is a reference to the `HttpServletResponse`.

Related Link:

1. [How to set up your server to send the correct MIME types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Configuring_server_MIME_types)
2. [Character Encoding problem with IBM's JSF and Ajax](http://www.visionfactory.com.au/blog/character_encoding_problem_with_ibm_s_js)

### Another answer

I've figured out what is causing the issue, but I do not understand why. The behavior exhibits itself when there is an on-error action on the request. Attached is a zip of a simple MPG with a request, response, and error rule that demonstrate this. The request has an on-error action, a simple xform that does a dp:reject (to force the error), and a results action. The error rule has a results action and a set var action. If you leave the on-error in, the response content-type is returned as "text/xml". If you remove the on-error, the content-type correctly returns "application/json". (Copied from following resource link)

Resource Link:

1. [How to set header Content-Type in error rule](http://dw.developer-works.com/article/10225067/How+to+set+header+Content-Type+in+error+rule)