# Reading request parameter values with UTF-8 chars in JSF

Tags: jsf, utf-8, parameters, request

I have a problem reading request paremeters from a GET request that contain special characters. Here's what I do:

I create the request url with javascript, and the value of drivername is encodeURIComponent('sorumluluğumuzu')
The result is this URL, which shows up correctly in firefox:
http://localhost:8080/driver/list.xhtml?sl=1&drivername=sorumlulu%C4%9Fumuzu

However, when I read the request param in my JSF bean:
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap()

The value equals to sorumluluÄumuzu

I'm experiencing this om Tomcat7 in JSF2, but we are noticing the same issue on Websphere6 and JSF1.2.

Any thoughts?

Comment: It's interesting how stackoverflow also is wrong on UTF8 characters... if you check the link, the %C4%9F is a different character than the Ä that is displayed further on in my post... :D

Answer (score 2):

Tomcat by default URL-decodes GET request parameters using ISO-8859-1. You need to change it to UTF-8 by the `URIEncoding` attribute in the `<Connector>` element of Tomcat's `/conf/server.xml`.

```
<Connector ... URIEncoding="UTF-8">
```

#### See also:

- [Unicode - How to get the characters right?](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html) - [JSP/Servlet request](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html#JSPServletRequest)

Comment: I managed indeed to get it working in Tomcat with that property.
Unfortunately I'm still in the woods with websphere. No luck so far in google, I'll keep looking, but suggestions welcome of course ;)

Comment: Websphere uses Tomcat under the covers. Look in the Websphere installation folder for a file named `server.xml`. You'll recognize much of the Tomcat documentation. Alternatively, try the filter in this answer instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2657515/detect-the-uri-encoding-automatically-in-tomcat

Comment: From what I can tell I believe Tomcat is only used in WebSphere CE, while I'm looking for a solution on Websphere AS7. No luck so far on server.xml :(

Comment: Oh, that's new to me (admittedly, the last time I worked with WAS, it was still WAS 5.x). Well, I [googled](http://www.google.com/search?q=websphere+utf-8+encoding) somewhat and the [first](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=%2Frzatz%2F51%2Fadmin%2Fhelp%2Ftrun_svr_utf.html) and [third](http://yashima-eng.blogspot.com/2007/06/config-encode-utf-8-on-websphere-61.html) hit led me to believe that setting `-Dclient.encoding.override=UTF-8` VM argument is the solution for you.

Comment: Afraid to say that this setting was already in place, and obviously didn't help much. We also set UTF-8 to every western language in encoding.properties file, again with no positive result :(

Comment: Interesting... I found that our WAS is already working in UTF8, hence why it's not working.

Eg. 
c%F4t%E9+conducteur => not correct, it's ANSI url encoding
c%C3%B4t%C3%A9%20conducteur => correct, utf8 encoding

It appears though that I must find a way to parse the first form correctly (and hence simulate the exact same functionality as my app on tomcat, without the URIEncoding="UTF-8" attribute