# Language issue with IE

Tags: jakarta-ee, utf-8

I have created a page, which shows a dropdown in Manipuri language. on change of this dropdown a javascript method is called, which creates url of another page and sets this selected value in URL as request parameter and the new page gets that value from the request.

Now, this works fine in Firefox browser but on IE, I am getting some other text than the one selected.

I have checked that my browser encoding is set to `UTF-8` and my jsp page also has encoding as `UTF-8`, is there any other thing that i need to check/change to correct this issue?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading request parameter values with UTF-8 chars in JSF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6427689/reading-request-parameter-values-with-utf-8-chars-in-jsf)

Comment: @dystroy: If that was the case, then wouldn't firefox browser respond the same, as it if something related to server. Trying that anyways.

Comment: In fact it's more complicated (hence my new link as possible duplicate). I solved all this long ago by transfering as url parameters not the value but ascii keys.

Comment: @dystroy: Changing get to post (with form) solved my problem.

Comment: Thank you for feedback. I suggest you answer your own question so that it may help somebody else, even if it's at least partially a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with GET URL, changed it to POST (using form submit and hidden variable) which worked.