# jsf url encoding h:outputlink

Tags: jsf, url, tomcat, unicode

I have a page which displays several links () to files which have special characters in their filenames. e.g. "SPRÜCHE.txt".

when i want to browse (GET-request) a link, i get following error:
".../SPRÃœCHE.txt was not found on this server."

But when i replace the special char "Ü" with its ASCII equivalent "%DC", it works fine.

I cannot replace all special chars so ASCII, because there are also other charsets in the filename involved, which cannot be encoded with ASCII (e.g. chinese)

I already tried it with lots of encoding methods, like URLEncoder.encode("","UTF-8"); but this returns me a unicode representation which cannot be parsed correctly in the url ("SPR%c3%9cCHE.txt cannot be found...")

is there a function, which makes a UTF-8 hyperlink / url web-safe?

I use tomcat 7

Comment: How exactly did you conclude that it's not supported by the browser? What exactly are the symptoms you observed on which you based this possible misassumption? Generally the browser doesn't care at all about this. Instead, it's the server who should be instructed to decode the incoming GET query string using the desired charset. Tomcat, for example, (incorrectly) defaults to ISO-8859-1 on this.

Comment: The JSF-Application which runs in the browser does find the file when I use %e4, but fails when I use %c3%a4. I have a UTF-8 Filter, which does request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");... so how can I tell Tomcat to use UTF-8 instead of ISO-8859-1? When I use %c3%a4 the browser replaces it by "ä", but fails to find the file

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6427689/reading-request-parameter-values-with-utf-8-chars-in-jsf/6441124#6441124

Comment: unfortunatyly it didn't help. the contents are shown correctly ("ä", "ü" and so on). Just in case i want to browse to a file which contains one of these chars it fails.

Comment: I don't understand the "it fails" part. Please elaborate it in developer's terms instead of enduser's terms.

Comment: i changed added the URIEncoding to the HTTP-Connector AND chanced the launch configuration of Tomcat in Eclipse. there was no effect at all. it tells me "...SPRÃœCHE.txt was not found on this server."

Comment: i have updatet the question. hope it is more clear now

Comment: it seems tomcat still cannot handle UTF-8 GET-Requests... even if I use the URIEncoding hook :(

Comment: Problem is not with the get request but with generated URL. If you expect UTF-8, you need to get UTF-8. You cannot resolve incorrect request on receiver but on sender.

1. You have to correctly escape html (browser parses it)
2. You have to generate correct UTF-8 escaped URL (browser uses it as GET url - if not Latin1, browser improvises).